# Introduce type constraint for compile time safety

Tags: scala

If we have a type class with some ADT as follow

```
trait MyRule {
  type T 
  class ResourceIdType[A](val value: A)
  case class StringResourceIdType(override val value: String) extends ResourceIdType(value)
  case class ListResourceIdType(override val value: List[Int]) extends ResourceIdType(value)

 def resourceType(rtm: T) : Any

private foo(rtm: T ) = {
  resourceType(rtm) match{
    case StringResourceIdType(s: String) =>
    case ListResourceIdType(l:List[Int]) =>
 ...
}
```

type class impls override `def resourceType` as follow

```
object FirstClient{
 implicit val clientRule = new MyRule{
    type T = SomeType
    def resourceType(rtm: T) = StringResourceIdType(rtm.name) //assume SomeType has a name property of type String
  }
}


object SecondClient{
  implicit val clientRule2 = New MyRule{
    type T = SomeType2
    def resourceType(rtm: T) = ListResourceIdType(rtm.ids) //assume SomeType2 has a ids property of type List[Int]
  }
}
```

Want to make `def resourceType(rtm: T) : Any` compile time type safe/checked by removing `Any` and replace with a valid type as `T <: ResourceIdType`. What would be the right way to address this?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided an compilable example. That would help to paste it directly into the REPL - to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type parameter in `MyRule trait` and refine it in each type classes:

```
trait MyRule {
  type T

  class ResourceIdType[A](val value: A)
  case class StringResourceIdType(override val value: String) extends ResourceIdType(value)
  case class ListResourceIdType(override val value: List[Int]) extends ResourceIdType(value)

  type F <: ResourceIdType[_]
  def resourceType(rtm: T) : F

  private def foo(rtm: T): Unit = {
    resourceType(rtm) match {
      case StringResourceIdType(s: String) =>
      case ListResourceIdType(l:List[Int]) =>
    }
  }
}

object FirstClient{
  implicit val clientRule = new MyRule{
    case class SomeType(name: String)
    type T = SomeType
    type F = StringResourceIdType
    def resourceType(rtm: T) = StringResourceIdType(rtm.name) //assume SomeType has a name property of type String
  }
}

object SecondClient{
  implicit val clientRule2 = new MyRule{
    case class SomeType2(ids: List[Int])
    type T = SomeType2
    type F = ListResourceIdType
    def resourceType(rtm: T) = ListResourceIdType(rtm.ids) //assume SomeType2 has a ids property of type List[Int]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex - Why do you have a return type of `Unit` in `foo`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be Unit. Just to make it compile here.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles. Please let me know if it addresses your problem.

```
package net

trait SomeType {
  def name: String
}

trait SomeType2 {
  def ids: List[Int]
}

// Introduce an Algebraic Data Type
class ResourceValue
case class StringValue(x: String) extends ResourceValue
case class ListIntsValue(x: List[Int]) extends ResourceValue

trait MyRule {
  type T 
  sealed trait ResourceIdType {
    val value: ResourceValue
  }
  case class StringResourceIdType(override val value: StringValue) extends ResourceIdType
  case class ListResourceIdType(override val value: ListIntsValue) extends ResourceIdType

 def resourceType(rtm: T): ResourceIdType

  private def foo(rtm: T): ResourceValue = {
    resourceType(rtm) match {
      case StringResourceIdType(s @ StringValue(_)) => s
      case ListResourceIdType(l @ ListIntsValue(_)) => l
    }
  }
}

object FirstClient{
 implicit val clientRule = new MyRule {
    type T = SomeType
    override def resourceType(rtm: T): ResourceIdType = 
      StringResourceIdType(StringValue(rtm.name)) 
  }
}


object SecondClient{
  implicit val clientRule2 = new MyRule {
    type T = SomeType2
    override def resourceType(rtm: T): ResourceIdType = 
      ListResourceIdType(ListIntsValue(rtm.ids))
  }
}
```